# Regex for detecting ABC/ABC 3 letters separated by a / in the middle

Tags: regex, autohotkey

I'm trying to detect 3 letters separated by a / followed by 3 after it

Not sure what expression it is for detecting it. 
[image]

Thank you for any suggestions

Answer (score 2):

You were close in your attempt, but `[0-3]` and `[0-9]` are character classes, not repetitions. Also, if you're looking to match entire strings, rather than substrings, you'll want to anchor your expression at the beginning and end with `^` and `$` respectively. Try this:

```
^[A-Za-z]{3}\/[A-Za-z]{3}$
```

Comment: Do you want exactly 3 characters or anywhere between zero and 3 characters? The question asks for "3 letters separated by a / followed by 3 after it".

Comment: I'm not the questioner haha / true, I missed that

Comment: According to the wording in the question, `{3}` is correct, not `{0,3}`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `[a-zA-Z]{3}/[a-zA-Z]{3}`. See http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.repetition.php for further info on repetition operators.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the regex dialect.  You have a few options:

This will match any word characters, including letters and numbers on either side of the '/':

```
/^\w{3}\/\w{3}$/
```

You may want only letters, in which case you can use this:

```
/^[a-z]{3}\/[a-z]{3}$/i
```

You may be using a very limited dialect, such as with the `grep` utility or within an IDE, in which case, this will work (make sure to enable 'ignore case' if you want lower and uppercase matches):

```
/^[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]\/[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]$/
```